# How does facebook token works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to write a process which downloads data about my ads.
Basically this is the code:
https://github.com/airflow-plugins/facebook_ads_plugin/blob/master/hooks/facebook_ads_hook.py

It construct a URI as:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v{api_version}/act_{account_id}/insights?{payload}
```

Where payload contains the `access_token`, `breakdowns`, `fields` etc.. 
Now, I passed over the facebook dev guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/  and it doesn't explain how do I get the `account_id` and the `token`.
It always leads to a user account that needs to log-in to facebook and then process the request.

I want to build a process that doesn't involve user action. Just download logs about my ads.

How can I do that? Where can I get the  `account_id` and the `token`.
In other systems like google and other they create a json file with credentials that is used for the outh. there doesn't seem to be equivalent with facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of use case, I would create a System User that is permissioned on all your ad accounts, following [this guide.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api/systemuser/) That will allow you to generate a token that can used without user login. (You can do the same for your personal facebook account, but that requires you to pass app verification. This can be done without that.)

Then to get the account ids of all the accounts the system user is permissioned on, query the "me/adaccounts" endpoint, using the access token generated for the system user. The docs for that [are here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/) You can use that to get a list of all the account ids.

Alternatively, if you only need one account id, you can get that straight from the facebook ads manager.

[image: get the account id!]